# Statistical difference in trend between two groups?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, trend

I have two groups/species and I have measured a certain variable at various distances (see plot). In particular, I have analyzed the correlation of this variable for each group between distance i and zero-distance. The error bars in the plot mark standard errors (StDev/sqrt(n)).

As one can see, the standard errors overlap at each distance, respectively. I would now like to test, whether the trends are significantly different (green: seems to stay leveled, orange: seems to decrease continuously).

What would be the right way to test this? Is there a statistical test that analyzes such incremental differences between groups? Or do I need to do a regression and test difference in slopes or something similar?

Many thanks!

[image]